# Jboss: postgres connection via standalone/configuration.xml

Tags: jboss

I tried several tutorials about how to add DB connection([mainly this one](https://developer.jboss.org/blogs/amartin-blog/2012/02/08/how-to-set-up-a-postgresql-jdbc-driver-on-jboss-7)) to jboss and seems a got lost.

Please correct my **steps** if I miss did something:

1. I added following description to `standalone/configuration.xml`:

   ```
    <datasources>
           <datasource  module="org.postgresql"  jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/Postgres" pool-name="Postgres" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
               <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
               <driver>postgresDriver</driver>
               <security>
                   <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                   <password>postgres</password>
               </security>
           </datasource>
           <drivers>
               <driver name="postgresDriver" module="org.postgresql">
                   <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
               </driver>
           </drivers>
       </datasources>
   ```
2. I created `org/postgres/main/` directory in `...modules/system/layers/base/org/` directory
3. I moved there `postgres-9.4.1208.jre6.jar` file.
4. I created in this location `org/postgres/main/` following `module.xml` file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.postgresql">
     <resources>
      <resource-root path="postgresql-9.4-1208.jre6.jar" />
     </resources>
   <dependencies>
     <module name="javax.api" />
     <module name="javax.transaction.api" />
   </dependencies>
   </module>
   ```
5. And my `persistence.xml` looks like:

   ```
   <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
            version="2.0">
     <persistence-unit name="movie-unit">
          <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/Postgres</jta-data-source>
     </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>
   ```

   ---

Then I start server with deployed *.war:

***/usr/local/share/jboss/bin/standalone.sh***

```
15:36:14,370 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.2.2.Final-redhat-1
15:36:14,502 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
15:36:14,556 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.1.1.GA (AS 7.2.1.Final-redhat-10) starting
15:36:15,188 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
15:36:15,190 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
15:36:15,192 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
15:36:15,198 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.16.GA-redhat-1
15:36:15,243 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
15:36:15,267 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.19.Final-redhat-2)
15:36:15,327 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
15:36:15,328 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "postgresDriver")
]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [org.postgresql]"
```

Please, verify my steps and help me figure out where is my mistake.

Comment: Maybe has typo in your config `org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSourc` -> `org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource`

Comment: @FedericoSierra, thanks, good catch, but I get the same error anyway

Comment: Check installation driver directory, must be `modules/system/layers/base/org/postgres/`

Comment: @FedericoSierra, I renamed everything to `postgres`, I get the same error: `Failed to load module for driver [org.postgres]`

Comment: it was typo in `<resource-root path=postgresql-9.4-1208.jre6.jar`>  should be `postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar`